# Suma de sub objetos mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Tengo una colección de mongo con la estructura:

```
{
  "_id":{"$oid":"5ebb1b2372ea8c57e6ca3681"},
  "detalle":[
    {
        "_id":{"$oid":"5ebb1b2372ea8c57e6ca3682"},
        "precio":2000,
        "kilos":2
    },
    {
        "_id":{"$oid":"5eb5c1042728d85b87014c49"},
        "precio":1500,
        "kilos":12
    }
  ],
  "proveedorid":{"$oid":"5eb5c1042728d85b87014c49"},
}
```

¿Como podria obtener el total por "proveedorid"? es decir, multiplicar el precio por los kilos, después, sumar todo el contenido dentro del objeto detalle, y después sumar todos los que tengan el mismo "proveedorid"

Actualmente lo hago con este código en nodeJs

```
let total = 0
let compras = await Compras.find({"proveedorid": id})
for(let key in compras){
    for(let keyd in compras[key].detalle){
        total += (compras[key].detalle[keyd].precio * compras[key].detalle[keyd].kilos)
    }
}
data.total = total
```

Quisiera saber como hacerlo desde la consulta.

Comment: Hay muchas formas de hacerlo, pero deberías mostrar primero lo que hayas intentado. Puedes leer [mcve] como referencia. Todas tus dudas están explicadas en la [documentación](https://docs.mongodb.com). Saludos

Comment: Actualmente lo hago con código en nodejs, soy nuevo con mongo y no tengo la minima idea de como hacerlo

Comment: Muestra el código que tienes de NodeJS. Haz clic en [edit] y agrégalo a la pregunta. De esa forma podemoa ver lo que tienes.

Comment: Listo, agregue el código js que tengo.

Answer (score 0):

En tu código primero haces `let compras = await Compras.find({"proveedorid": id})` que es para obtener únicamente los datos de un único `proveedorid`, pero luego dices que quieres "sumar todos los que tengan el mismo `proveedorid`", lo que me hace dudar si quieres filtrar los resultados según el ID o no.

Sea como sea esta es la query que necesitas (si he entendido bien):

- Primero `$unwind` en el array detalle para tener los diferentes objetos que lo componen.
- Después añadir un campo con el total de cada document multiplicando kgs por precio.
- Y por último agrupar según el id del proovedor sumando el total.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$detalle"
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "total": {
        "$multiply": [
          "$detalle.kilos",
          "$detalle.precio"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$proveedorid",
      "total": {
        "$sum": "$total"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Ejemplo [aquí](https://mongoplayground.net/p/c0qrdxNnxL1)

Y si lo que necesitas es filtar por un `proveedorid` específico únicamente tienes que añadir un paso extra al inicio:

```
{
  "$match": {
    "proveedorid": "5eb5c1042728d85b87014c49"
  }
}
```

Ejemplo [aquí](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vMwlfGdtFKo)